# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext'

Tags: javascript, canvas, jspdf

Hi guys I am new to JS and still learning. Now that is out of the way, I am trying to create a pdf when a button is clicked. However, I am getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null".

I am creating two canvases. The first one works fine but I cannot understand why is it not working for the second one. I have searched the error and have learnt that it usually occurs when the code runs before html loads. However, my script code is at the end of body. Also the error occurs at the second getContext('2d') even before the image is referenced not the first one.

```
function cPdf() {

    //  The code below creates a new canvas to draw the chart
    //****************************************************************


    var conHeight = document.getElementById("chart-container").offsetHeight;
    var conWidth = document.getElementById("chart-container").offsetWidth;

    var pdfCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    pdfCanvas.id = "canvasPdf";
    pdfCanvas.width = conWidth;
    pdfCanvas.height = conHeight;

    var pdfctx = pdfCanvas.getContext("2d");

    var canvasHeight = document.getElementById("chart").offsetHeight;
    var canvasWidth = document.getElementById("chart").offsetWidth;

    pdfctx.drawImage(document.getElementById("chart"), 0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

    //*****************************************************************
    //  Chart copied on canvas and ready to be added to the pdf 

    //  The code below creates a new canvas to draw the logo
    //****************************************************************   

    var myCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    myCanvas.setAttribute("id", "logoCanvas");
    myCanvas.width = 250;
    myCanvas.height = 150;
    //
        var c = document.getElementById("logoCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    //  var img = document.getElementById("logo");
    //  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    //*****************************************************************
    //  logo copied on canvas and ready to be added to the pdf

    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', "A4");
    pdf.setFont("Lucida Grande");

    pdf.addImage(pdfCanvas, 'PNG', 35, 10);

    source = document.getElementById("oTable");
    margins = {
        top: 80,
        bottom: 20,
        left: 20,
        width: 400
    };
    pdf.fromHTML(
        source,
        margins.left,
        margins.top, {
            // y coord
            width: margins.width;
        },
        function () {
            pdf.save("Test.pdf");
        },
        margins
    );
}
'''
```

Comment: when is `cPdf` called? is the dom ready?

Comment: `document.getElementById("logoCanvas")` won’t work. You just created it, but didn’t put it in the DOM. Why even do it like that? You already have a reference to your canvas; just do `var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");`. You’re doing it correctly with `pdfCanvas`.

Comment: Ah right so I need to add canvas to DOM before I can use `getElementByID`. It is working fine with `var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");`. Thanks @user4642212

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById` does work with dynamically added elements.
You can use myCanvas directly like your first getContext().

```
// var c = document.getElementById("logoCanvas");
// var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
```

If you want to use `queryElementById()` for your canvas, you shoud append elemnet before.

Comment: _“`document.getElementById` does work with dynamically added elements”_ — That sentence is strange. It _doesn’t_ work for elements that are _not in the DOM_. What do you mean by “dynamically added”? Created? Added to the DOM?